# Use Fortify sourceanalyzer with mingw

Tags: c++, cygwin, mingw, fortify

I use mingw with cygwin to compile my c/c++ code.
I came to know about fortify sourceanalyzer tool for static analysis. Before putting efforts and money I want to know whether it supports mingw along with cygwin?

If someone has used it in this way, please share your learning.

Comment: It looks like you need the free trial to find out how it works, including what os and whether tied to specific compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Currently mingw / cygwin is not supported. From a windows perspective, Fortify on Demand supports gcc, g++, Oracle javac, cl / Visual Studio.